# Additional parameters in function

Tags: contract-development, web3js, contract-design

As we know, in every function call we can add {from: "address, value:5, gass: 420000}. I wondered who provides these capabilities? Is it Solidity, VM or web3.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, do you want to know who enters the values, or who forces you to place values there?   What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @thefett My question is more general than that. I'd like to know who allows me to have {from: "address, value:5, gass: 420000} in a function. Is it web3, Solidity or VM?

Answer (score 1):

Web3 is what gives you that interface:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

It's then turned into bytcode which the EVM can read.  It's required by the EVM as laid out in the yellow paper (bottom of pg 10) - https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf